# Is the Lorentz boost boosting me or the frame?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, conventions, observers

I am starting to dive deeper into Special Relativity, but something that always confuses me is whether the Lorentz boost is the increase in my own velocity to catch up with moving objects or the decrease in velocity of the frame with the moving objects such that they become stationary.

Say I start in frame F with an object moving with velocity $v$ in the $+x$ direction. If I move to a frame in which this object is stationary, is $β$ positive or negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion is implicit in the way the question was phrased:

> If I move to a frame in which this object is stationary, is β
> positive or negative?

This reads like you are implying that $\beta$ is an inherent property of a certain frame, which is incorrect. $\beta$ is associated with the *transformation* between two frames, and the sign of $\beta$ is determined by the way we define this transformation. Since $\beta=v/c$, the sign of $v$ clearly determines the sign of $\beta$, and the sign of $v$ is straightforwardly determined by which frame we consider *first* when computing our transformation.

To explain that, let's take your example, and begin by considering initially frame $F$, and denote the object's frame as $F'$. Since $F'$ is moving in the positive $x$ direction with respect to $F$, our relative speed $v$ will be positive, hence also $\beta$ is positive. The transformation from the coordinate variables $(t,x)$ in $F$ to coordinate variables $(t',x')$ in $F'$ will take the form:

$$\Lambda_{F \rightarrow F'} = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & -\beta\gamma\\\ -\beta\gamma & \gamma\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$

accordingly, the inverse transformation from $F'$ to $F$ will be:

$$\Lambda_{F' \rightarrow F} = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & \beta\gamma\\\ \beta\gamma & \gamma\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

and one may verify that $\Lambda_{F' \rightarrow F}\Lambda_{F \rightarrow F'}=I$

Now however, let's start by considering frame $F'$. Frame $F$ is now seen to move away along the negative $x$ direction of $F'$, hence the $\beta$ for the transformation we will now construct will be *negative*! Since this is no longer the same $\beta$ as before, let's call it $\beta'$, and write basically the same transformations as before, only now first for going from $F'$ to $F$ and then back:

$$\Lambda_{F' \rightarrow F} = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & -\beta'\gamma\\\ -\beta'\gamma & \gamma\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}$$

$$\Lambda_{F \rightarrow F'} = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & \beta'\gamma\\\ \beta'\gamma & \gamma\end{bmatrix}\tag{4}$$

(Note that the $\gamma$'s *are* the same ones as before, since they only depend on $v^2$!)

Now, since we have computed the *same* pair of transformations, albeit in slightly different ways, our results *must* agree! But this is clearly the case, because since $\beta = -\beta'$ it becomes immediately apparent that we have $(1)=(4)$ and $(2)=(3)$, so the change of sign of $\beta$ did not really affect the transformations, as we should have expected!

Comment: Take my upvote; I think it is sad that you didn't write down using the matrices to actually do some boosting; I'll do it here if space allows. Also, you should have noted that boost matrices can do both "boosting me" and "boosting frames", hence explaining the confusion of the OP, and that OP should thus pay attention to the wording. $$\begin{pmatrix}\gamma&-\gamma\beta\\-\gamma\beta&\gamma\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t\\\beta t\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t/\gamma\\0\end{pmatrix}$$shows that something moving can be boosted to a stop and _vice versa_

Comment: Thank you @naturallyInconsistent, much appreciated. I think btw it should be $ct$ rather than $t$ right? :) Unless we opt for using some weird time units, or put $c=1$... doesn't really matter, your point is well taken :)

Comment: Yes. I was trusting that people who use $\beta$ are already _enlightened_ enough to know that $ct$ comes as a pair. </haughtiness maximus>

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Indeed... I only mentioned that because I have already committed the pedestrian act of mentioning $c$ explicitly in my answer... :D

Comment: @Amit Thanks! Your initial remark is very correct, it turns out that I was thinking the right thing but backwards. In the specific problem I was trying to solve I was applying the transformation say from frame F to F', when it should've been the opposite (hence why my confusion was with the sign). Anyhow, thanks a lot for the help, your answer was very elucidating!

Answer (score 0):

If an object is moving with velocity $v$ in the +$\hat x$ direction, then its trajectory is described by the equation
$$x = v t$$

If you perform a boost with velocity parameter $\beta$, then your new coordinates $(x',t')$ are related to your old ones $(x,t)$ by

$$\matrix{x' = \gamma(x - \beta ct) \\ ct' = \gamma(ct - \beta x)}$$

Plugging in $x = vt$, these equations become
$$\matrix{x' = \gamma(v-\beta c)t \\ ct' = \gamma(1 - \beta v/c) ct } \implies x' = \frac{v-\beta c}{1-\beta v/c}t'$$

This is equal to zero if $\beta = v/c$. Therefore,

> Say I start in frame F with an object moving with velocity $v$ in the $+x$ direction. If I move to a frame in which this object is stationary, is $β$ positive or negative?

Positive.

Answer (score -1):

$\beta$ has the same sign in both frames (and doesn't matter for the Lorentz factor, which only cares about $\beta ^2$, anyway). A Lorentz boost is just a Lorentz transformation without rotation. A Lorentz transformation is a linear transformation of the coordinate system associated with one frame to the coordinate system associated with a different frame. If you have some measurements taken in one frame, Lorentz boost tells you what the corresponding measurements should be in another frame, neglecting Doppler effect.